# Inserting mysql data into a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Trying to complete a tutorial and am trying to retrofit the styling. 
I know the whole sheet of code may be anything from current, 
but its helping me break down the parts and understand the whole.

That said, I am trying to insert the mysql data into divs instead of a table. 
(for the thought of more responsive CSS design possibilities)

Any help would be awesome.

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 4 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 4");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="83%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            $' . $price . '<br />
            <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
    }
} else {
    $dynamicList = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent">
  <table width="85%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" valign="top"><h3></h3>
      <p><br />
        <br />
        </p></td>
    <td width="66%" align="center">
        <h3>The Shop </h3>
      <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?><br />
        </p>
      <p><br />
      </p></td>
    <td width="20%" valign="top"><h3></h3>
        <p></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </div>
  <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you basically want to change the tr and tds into divs with classes?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this should get you headed in the right direction (Ignore the ... accordingly)

```
<?php
  ...
  $dynamicList .= '
  <div>
    <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="77" height="102" border="1" /></a>
  </div>
  <div>' . $product_name . '<br />
    $' . $price . '<br />
    <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a>
  </div>';
  ...
?>

...

<div id="pageContent">
  <h3>The Shop </h3>
  <?php echo $dynamicList; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Jonsuh, Thank you! And in case I forgot... Thank you.

Comment: jonsuh, What is the best CSS method for making the divs side by side?

Comment: @newneub Probably `float: left` and giving them appropriate widths. Would appreciate it if you could upvote and accept the answer as well.

Comment: jonsuh, hopefully I was able to upvote this properly. I added a new question regarding this. Would be very grateful if you took a look at it. Having a hard time to order the arrays within the divs as if they were an ordered list. A discerning eye towards solving this problem would be much obliged.